# php > remote_addr returns a non-ip like result

Tags: php, ip, server-variables

Out of this code below,

```
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])){
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
  }else{
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
```

I ended up getting an IP like this:

```
2605:6001:e653:f900:f98f:84a2:cdff:e83f
```

Could someone interpret this pls? 
Should not all IPs be in the form of XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ?

Comment: Looks like it might be a ipv6.

Comment: IPv6 addresses have a size of 128 bits. Therefore, IPv6 has a vastly enlarged address space compared to IPv4.

Comment: See the wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address

Comment: Does that mean that with the emergence of this new format all the db fields that are cut out for 15 chars to choke?